# Show that cartesian product of a measurable set with $\mathbb{R}$ is measurable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $S\subset \mathbb{R}$ be measurable. Show that $S$ is measurable if and onlt if $S\times \mathbb{R}$ is measurable.

My attempt:
If $S$ is measurable, there exist open $U\subset \mathbb{R}$, closed $V\subset \mathbb{R}$ s.t.

$$U\supset S \supset V$$

s.t. $\lambda(U\setminus V)<\epsilon$. Also $U\times \mathbb{R} \supset S\times \mathbb{R} \supset V\times \mathbb{R}$ but I'm not sure how to show the difference in Lebesgue measure can be controlled part. Do I need to take any subset of $S\times \mathbb{R}$ and look at top and bottom approximations and then estimate the difference in Lebesgue measure?

I think this will help me figure out how to prove the other direction as well.

Comment: It is useful to try to write your set as the preimage of a measurable set under a measurable function. For example $$f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2, f(x)=(x,1)$$ is continuous and thus measurable. Hence, $S=f^{-1}(S\times \mathbb{R})$ is measurable as $S\times \mathbb{R}$ and $f$ are measurable.

Comment: For the other direction consider $g(x,y)=x$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven That is very neat and concise!

Comment: Thanks :) I think this is in general a good idea. Same for showing compactness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this set $M = \{A\in\cal{B}(\mathbb{R})| A\times \mathbb{R} \in \cal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)\}.$   If $A$ is open, $A\in M$.  What else can you say about $M$?

Comment: Do you mean $M=\{A\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})|A\times \mathbb{R}\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R^2})\}$?

Comment: Yep, I just fixed that in an edit.

Comment: Because we are trying to prove $A$ is measurable if and only if $A\times \mathbb{R}$ is measurable, is $M=\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$?

Answer (score -1):

Let's show first that if $A$ is measurable then $A\times \mathbb{R}$ is measurable.  It is enough to consider the case $A$ bounded.  Then it is enough to show that $A \times I$ is measurable for a bounded open interval. Now, for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists  $K\subset A \subset U$, $K$ compact, $U$ open, such that $\mu(U \backslash K) < \epsilon$. Take $J$ compact, $J\subset I$. We get $J\times K \subset A\times I \subset U\times I$, $\ \ J\times K$ compact, and $U\times I$ open $\ldots$.

Assume now that $A$ is not measurable. Let us show that $A\times I$ is not measurable.  May assume that $A$ is bounded.  Take $M\subset A$, $M$ measurable, of largest possible measure, and $N\supset A$, $N$, measurable, of smallest possible measure. Since $A$ is not measurable, we have $\mu(M) < \mu (N)$.

Let us show that $M\times I \subset A\times I$ is a measurable subset of $A\times I$ of largest possible measure. For this, it is enough to show that every measurable subset $K$ of $(A\backslash M) \times I $ has measure zero. We may assume $K$ compact. The projection of $K$ onto the first component is a compact subset $L$ of $A\backslash M$, and so of measure $0$. Since $K \subset L\times I$, we get $\mu(K) \le \mu(L\times I) = 0\cdot |I| = 0$. Similarly we show that $N\times I$ is a measurable set of smallest measure containing $A\times I$.

From the above it follows that $A\times I$ is not measurable.